# Get user properties by user id Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-analytics, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way to get the user properties of a specific user by its ID. And if it is, can I access those properties using Cloud Functions? For example: I need to get the "language" user property of a user by using its ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Cloud Functions you should use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node) to interact with Firebase services (Authentication, Firestore, Storage, etc).

You can therefore do as follows to get details from a user, using the [`getUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#get-user) method:

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
```

More details and examples [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) on how to manage users through the Admin SDK.

---

Note however that the [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) and [`UserRecord`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord.html) objects do not have a `language` property.

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to use user properties to get specifically the language, but that's ok, I think the API just doesn't support that functionality right now. Thank you.

Comment: If needed you can save some extra user data into a Firestore document that has the same ID than the user UID. Then you can fetch this doc when needed.